# Magento 2 - what event should I observe to change/intercept the calculation of subtotals on Cart

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer, xml

I am using Magento 2.

I made an observer that observes anytime a new item is added to the cart. The observer works properly, I also managed to create a single product discount with this observer, here is the events.xml file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="PerfectStorm_Pricecalculations_Addtocart" instance="PerfectStorm\Pricecalculations\Observer\PricecalculationsAfterAddtoCart" />
</event>
```

The problem is, I want to do the same in order to change and intercept the calculation of the subtotals in the cart for each item. But I don't know what event should I observe.

Can you please advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create a plugin for the class Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal, and to add some functionality to the collect function.

di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal">
        <plugin name="myPluginUniquId" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and the Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Quote/Address/Total.php file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Quote/Address/Total;

class Subtotal{

public function aroundCollect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ){
        //do something before the subtotal calculation

        $returnValue = $proceed($quote, $shippingAssignment, total);

       //do something after the subtotal calculation

        return $returnValue;
    }

}
```